# Creating a receipt style UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am attempting to create a view to show a list of items and prices using two UILabels in a UIView.

In my UIViewController I call my subview *LineItemView* and pass data, and return the UIView to the main view that will hold the subviews.

**Though my view is returning empty. The strings are null.**

[image: After it is called]

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "LineItemView.h"
//...
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewCharges;
//...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadData];

}

- (void) loadData {
    //Here we will fill in the viewCharges view
    LineItemView * view = [[LineItemView alloc]init];
    view.linePrice = @"1.00";
    view.lineItem  = @"Something";
    [self.viewCharges addSubview:view];

}
```

***LineItemView.h***

```
@interface LineItemView : UIView {
    UILabel * lblLineItem, *lblLinePrice;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* lineItem;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* linePrice;
```

***LineItemView.m***

```
#define LABEL_MINIMUM_HEIGHT         32
#define VERTICAL_MARGIN              5
#define HORIZONTAL_MARGIN            10

@implementation LineItemView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self createUI];
        [self updateData];
        NSLog(@"\n\n\n Line Item: %@ Price: %@ \n\n\n", self.lineItem, self.linePrice);

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) createUI {
    lblLineItem = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    lblLineItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self addSubview:lblLineItem];

    lblLinePrice = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    lblLinePrice.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self addSubview:lblLinePrice];

}

- (void) updateLayout {
    lblLineItem.frame  = CGRectMake(HORIZONTAL_MARGIN, VERTICAL_MARGIN, 300, 35);
    lblLinePrice.frame = CGRectMake(lblLineItem.frame.origin.x + lblLineItem.frame.size.width + HORIZONTAL_MARGIN, VERTICAL_MARGIN, 80, 35);
}

- (void) updateData {
     lblLineItem.text = self.lineItem;
     lblLinePrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", [self.linePrice floatValue]];
}

- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self updateLayout];
}
```

***What am I doing wrong? 
If I want to continue calling LineItemView, how do I ensure that it is added below the previous one and ensure the viewCharges size is readjusted to fit all the subviews?***

Comment: You need to call `updateData` after you set the values for `linePrice`and `lineItem`. But my advise, use a `UITableView` it will handle large sets of data better.

Comment: The strings are null on init.

Comment: Yes and that is correct, because the init is called when you init the view: `LineItemView * view = [[LineItemView alloc]init];`

Comment: you should be calling [LineItemView alloc]initWithFrame....

Comment: Facepalm. It's always the little things.

Comment: Still your strings will be nil on init.

Comment: How do I fix that @rckoenes

Comment: Either you create a custom `init` in which you pass the values or you call the `updateData` after you set values.

Comment: I guess I am failing to understand. The values are set when the view is created in the ViewController.

Comment: The `initWithFrame:` method is called before you assign the `linePrice` or  `linePrice`. You either add a new init method or override the setters of `linePrice` or  `linePrice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution using setters:**

```
@implementation LineItemView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self createUI];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) createUI {
    lblLineItem = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    lblLineItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self addSubview:lblLineItem];

    lblLinePrice = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    lblLinePrice.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self addSubview:lblLinePrice];

}

- (void) updateLayout {
    lblLineItem.frame  = CGRectMake(HORIZONTAL_MARGIN, VERTICAL_MARGIN, 300, 35);
    lblLinePrice.frame = CGRectMake(lblLineItem.frame.origin.x + lblLineItem.frame.size.width + HORIZONTAL_MARGIN, VERTICAL_MARGIN, 80, 35);
}

- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self updateLayout];
}

- (void)setLineItem:(NSSTring *)lineItem {
    _lineItem = lineItem;
    lblLineItem.text = self.lineItem;
}

- (void)setLinePrice:(NSNumber *)linePrice {
    _linePrice = linePrice;
     lblLinePrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", [self.linePrice floatValue]];
}
```